How does the MINA SSHD service verify the CA certificate offered by the client?
I overwrote the authenticate method of the PublickeyAuthenticator.java and registered it with the ssh server.
sshServer.setPublickeyAuthenticator(publicKeyAuth);

But when the client provides the key and certificate, MINA SSHD displays an error:
2024-12-25 17:29:30.882 sshd-SshServer[53600a30](port=2222)-nio2-thread-5 WARN  org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerUserAuthService.warn - handleUserAuthRequestMessage(ServerSessionImpl[null@/127.0.0.1:56562]) Failed (InvalidKeyException) to authenticate using factory method=publickey: Supplied key (org.apache.sshd.common.config.keys.OpenSshCertificateImpl) is not a RSAPublicKey instance

After debugging, I found that the problem is that when MINA SSHD initializes the signature verifier of the public key, the public key passed in is of type OpenSshCertificateImpl, while Signature expects an RSAPublicKey object.
Why does this problem occur? How can I solve it?
==========update==========
I rewrote the initVerifier function in SignatureRSA.java and now I can login correctly.
Old initVerifier function:
public void initVerifier(SessionContext session, PublicKey key) throws Exception {
      super.initVerifier(session, key);
      RSAKey rsaKey = ValidateUtils.checkInstanceOf(key, RSAKey.class, "Not an RSA key");
      verifierSignatureSize = getVerifierSignatureSize(rsaKey);
}

I overwrote the initVerifier function:
public void initVerifier(SessionContext session, PublicKey key) throws Exception {
      if (key instanceof OpenSshCertificate){
          super.initVerifier(session, ((OpenSshCertificate) key).getCertPubKey());
          RSAKey rsaKey = ValidateUtils.checkInstanceOf(((OpenSshCertificate) key).getCertPubKey(), RSAKey.class, "Not an RSA key");
          verifierSignatureSize = getVerifierSignatureSize(rsaKey);
      }else {
          super.initVerifier(session, key);
          RSAKey rsaKey = ValidateUtils.checkInstanceOf(key, RSAKey.class, "Not an RSA key");
          verifierSignatureSize = getVerifierSignatureSize(rsaKey);
      }
  }

I am still curious as to why this happens？ And whether there are any hidden dangers in my modification.

Are you able to log in non-programmatically using the same private key?

Yes, I can log in to the configured openssh server with this certificate

I would make sure that full logging is turned on so you can see exactly what's occurring at the client
